# How to get across pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, lvalue

Here is a little piece of code that i am unable to understand

```
int x=30, *y, *z;
y=&x; 
z=y;
//y++ = z++;
//*y++ = *z++;
x++;
printf("x=%p, y=%p, z=%p y=%p\n ", &x, y,z,y++);
return 0;
```

These doubts are haunting me:
why is `(z++ = y++;)` invalid assignment while `(z = y)` valid.                            what does this assignment `(*y++ = *z++)` mean?

Furthermore, if I run this program i am getting following output:

x = 0028FF04 , y = 0028FF08, z = 0028FF04 y = 0028FF04
while my expectation is
x = 0028FF04 , y = 0028FF04, z = 0028FF04 y = 0028FF08

Comment: just guess the output of this code `x = 1`, `printf("%d\t%d\t%d", x++, x, ++x)` run it in your compiler and compare with your expected result.

Answer (score 4):

In assignment, there is left side and there is right side. Left side is required to be so called **lvalue** (l for left), which essentially means it must be a variable and not a result of calculation or literal. You can assign `x = 5 + 2`, but you cannot assign `5 + 2 = x`.

You cannot assign `z++ = y++` becase `z++` is not lvalue. It is an expression the result of which is value of `z` before incrementation. It is not reference to the variable `z` or anything like that.

However, you can assign `*z++ = *y++`, because here you deal with pointers. Essentially the left side (right side does not matter, only lvalue restriction matters here) means: increment `z`, get its value before incrementation and dereference it (so the value of `z` should be an address, which it totally is). That gives you a valid lvalue.

Answer (score 2):

> why is (z++ = y++;) invalid assignment while (z = y) valid?

Sub-expressions `Z++` and `Y++` both gives a value. For assigning a value of a sub-expression you need an l-value, you can't assign a value to another value. Assigning `y++` to `z++` is like assigning `3` to `4` as `3 = 4`.  On the other hand `z` is an l-value and there is no problem in assigning a value to it, and that's why `z = y` is a valid expression.

> what does this assignment (*y++ = *z++) mean?

This assignment means that you are assigning the value of the variable that `z` points to into the variable that `y` points to and then incrementing `y` and `z` ( as compiler sees this as `*(y++) = *(z++)` ).

> Furthermore, if I run this program i am getting following output:
>   x = 0028FF04 , y = 0028FF08, z = 0028FF04 y = 0028FF04
>   while my expectation is
>   x = 0028FF04 , y = 0028FF04, z = 0028FF04 y = 0028FF08 ?

Reason behind this is the statement:

```
printf("x=%p, y=%p, z=%p y=%p\n ", &x, y,z,y++);
```

in which using `y` and `y++` together invokes undefined behavior. You're using expressions with side effects that depend on each other, but in a context where the order these side effects are going to be applied is undefined. Therefore, there can be no guarantees that you'll get the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

let me give you my understaning of your questions.
As for the first

> what does this assignment (*y++ = *z++) mean?

the answers above all give the reasonable solutions, and i won't give a third one.

the second

> Furthermore, if I run this program i am getting following output:
>     x = 0028FF04 , y = 0028FF08, z = 0028FF04 y = 0028FF04
>     while my expectation is
>     x = 0028FF04 , y = 0028FF04, z = 0028FF04 y = 0028FF08 ?

the differrence between your expection and the real output results from the call-convention-of-c-function. many c compilers use cdecl-call-convention by default, that is the parameters is passed into the stack form the right to the lefat. thus,"y++" goes into the stack fisrt, now you should think ot the side-effect of "++"operator.
so, "y" is passed into stack,and the it is incremented. and when the third parameter is  passed, "y" has become "y+1"

i am not sure if i have given the understandable answer,and maybe i have made some mistakes. welcome your correction.

ps:it has something to do with the evaluation order of the parameters.

Comment: Statement like `printf("%d, %d", x, x++)` always invokes undefined behavior. Also there is no guarantee that `y++` evaluates first.

Comment: what do you mean by "undefined behavior"? different output between each running of the same executable-file,or between different executable-files generated by different compilers??if it's just as you say,i cannot give a reasonable explanation.and i guess it may have to do with the codes difference lying in the compiler mess of itsself(oh,i am just talking nonsense by saying this,donot believe)

Comment: I suggest you to read [Sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) and this [C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html).

Comment: Yep. i've learned something of sequence point. The parameter evaluation order do affects the hehaviour and not every compiler has specified behaviour about this kind of expressions. But for one compiler regulation, the call-convention make a difference for the question,right?